Angular Js ui-grid vertical scroll moving up when scrolled horizonatally
I'm using Angular UI grid,facing this issue,
when scrolled the vertical scroll to bottom last and if try to move horizontal scroll to right corner, vertical scroll is, moving up
please refer this for more info : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/6981
is there a workaround to fix this
can try the above mentioned issue here : http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20213%20Auto-Resizing
I've found that inline margin is applied to rows when horizontally scrolled to right, when i tried to make that margin to 0, I'm observing whitespace in the left side of the grid
element {
    margin : 0px;
}

additional info: if I increase the width of whole grid, the I'm not seeing this issue, but the columns are resizable, if user tries to resize(increase size) the columns and try the above steps again it is reproducing.
